# How to deserialize json list, error: Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to List<or_leadsJSON>

Tags: apex, class, callout, deserialize

I an trying to deserialize a Json string to use in my callout but get the error 
 Invalid conversion from runtime type `List<ANY>` to `List<or_guestsJSON>`

Callout

```
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
           List<or_leadsJSON> input = (List<or_leadsJSON>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            }
```

Class object

```
public class or_leadsJSON{
    class cls_0 {
        public String city; //Irvine
        public String state;    //California
    }
    class cls_agency {
        public String uid;  //0000-0000-0000-0000-0000
        public String name; //Responseev
    }
    class cls_property {
        public String uid;  //0000-0000-0000-0000-0000
        public boolean isActive;
        public String currencyRep; //USD
    }
    class cls_photos {
        public String url;  //https://www.orbirental.com/img/uploader/view_0.jpg
        public String description;  //my house
    }
    class cls_stayDetails {
        public String departureDate;    //2017-02-25 11:00:00.0
        public String arrivalDate;  //2017-02-24 15:00:00.0
        public String extraNotes;   //Some notes
    }
    public static or_leadsJSON parse(String json){
        String jsonReplace =  json.replace('"currency":', '"currencyRep":');
        return (or_leadsJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonReplace, or_leadsJSON.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
List<or_guestsJSON> input = (List<or_guestsJSON>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(
    response.getBody()
);
```

to this:

```
List<or_guestsJSON> input = (List<or_guestsJSON>) JSON.deserialize(
    response.getBody(),
    List<or_guestsJSON>.class
);
```

so that the parser has the type information it needs to create the correct type which in this case is a list.

(For arrays `deserializeUntyped` always creates the most generic collection type of `List<Object>`. You can still work with that, but you need additional code to convert to the correct type of list so better to use `deserialize` when possible.)

Comment: I have edited my question with leads instead of guests. When I debug this I get : input(or_leadsJSON:[], or_leadsJSON:[], or_leadsJSON:[], or_leadsJSON:[], or_leadsJSON:[], or_leadsJSON:[], or_leadsJSON:[], or_leadsJSON:[])

Comment: @Thomas Not to sure what you mean here. Bottom line is that if the JSON has a fixed structure use `deserialize` with an explicit type (class).

Comment: In this case isnt my or_leadsJSON empty or how do I get cls_stayDetails arrivalDate?

Comment: @Thomas Best you add a sample of the JSON that fails to the question. Your class `or_leadsJSON` is entirely missing any properties which would give you the result you see. If you are trying to support multiple formats in one piece of code, you will need to use `deserializeUntyped` and handle the differences using explicit map-access code.

Answer (score 3):

if you know a structure of JSON and already have created wrapper to store deserialized result - use `deserialize` method with type as second param of method

```
or_guestsJSON input = JSON.deserialize(jsonReplace, or_leadsJSON.class);
```

---

you already have `parse` method, as [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) generates it as well (looks like you used this tool)

```
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    or_guestsJSON input = or_guestsJSON.parse(response.getBody());
}
```